# Searching an XML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Im trying to search an xml file with input i get from a textfield. Im able to loop through the file and compare the strings to eachother, so they basicly match if the strings are exactly the same. I want to be able to search with just one word and find all the results containing this word.

In other words if I search for "lorem" I want it to find "lorem ipsum".

```
function searchXML(){
  $.get("xml/ResolvedIssues.xml",{},function(xml){

    input = document.getElementById("inputSearch").value;
    myHTMLOutput = '';
    myHTMLOutput += '<h3>Tickets containing "';
    myHTMLOutput += input;
    myHTMLOutput += '"</h3>'

    $('Table1',xml).each(function(i) {
      application = $(this).find("Application").text();
      module = $(this).find("Module").text();
      ticket = $(this).find("Ticket_x0023_").text();
      summary = $(this).find("Summary").text();
      detail= $(this).find("Details").text();
      problem = $(this).find("Problem_Flag").text();
      version = $(this).find("Version").text();
      build = $(this).find("Build").text();
      checked = $(this).find("Checked_In").text();
      status = $(this).find("Status").text();

      if (input == module || input == ticket || input == summary ||
        input == detail || input == problem || input == version ||
        input == build || input == checked || input == status) {

        $('#demo').html('');
        mydata = BuildTable(application, module, ticket, summary, detail, problem, version, build, checked, status);
        myHTMLOutput = myHTMLOutput + mydata;

      };

    });

    $("#demo").append(myHTMLOutput);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
if (input == module || input == ticket || input == summary ||
    input == detail || input == problem || input == version ||
    input == build || input == checked || input == status) {
```

Try this instead:

```
if ((module + ticket + summary + detail + problem + version +
    build + checked + status).indexOf(input) > -1) {
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for. indexOf() should have capital "o".

Comment: Oops, sorry, I fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

### jQuery .contents()

Description: Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, **including text** and comment **nodes**.

https://api.jquery.com/contents/